# C# WPF not rendering correctly , misses right and lower bounds

Tags: c#, wpf

Right and Lower side of components are not rendered (that button and two text boxs),may I know why ? Is anything wrong with my xaml file or it is because of my environment or something else ?

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        Width="120"
        Height="40"
        Name="Browse_File"
        Content="Browse Files"
        FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,664,371"></Button>


    <TextBlock
        Foreground="Red"
        Text="Files not to organize :"
        Height="30"
        Width="300" Margin="484,10,10,381"></TextBlock>
    <TextBox

        Height="150"
        Width="300" Margin="484,40,10,231"

        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>



    <TextBlock
        Foreground="Blue"
        Text="Files to organize :"
        Height="30"
        Width="300" Margin="484,195,10,196"></TextBlock>

    <TextBox

        Height="150"
        Width="300" Margin="484,225,10,46"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

[image: Attached image]

After changing the xaml a little bit , everything is fine . Here is what I have changed :

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        Width="100"
        Height="30"
        Name="Browse_File"
        Content="Browse Files"
        Margin="10,10,664,371"></Button>


    <TextBlock
        Foreground="Red"
        Text="Files not to organize :"
        Height="30"
        Width="300" Margin="484,10,10,381"></TextBlock>

    <TextBox
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

        Height="140"
        Width="290" Margin="484,40,10,231"

        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>



    <TextBlock
        Foreground="Blue"
        Text="Files to organize :"
        Height="30"
        Width="300" Margin="484,195,10,196"></TextBlock>

    <TextBox

        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

        Height="140"
        Width="290" Margin="484,225,10,46"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>

</Grid>
```

[image: Now rendering problem is fixed]

I want to understand more about it , can anyone provide me with a better understandings on this , it will be very nice.

Comment: Grid has no size and you’re not defining any rows or columns or putting controls in them. I’m assuming the grid just is too small. I would suggest checking out how to use it

Comment: Do not use Margins for layout. Instead, add Row- and ColumnDefinitions to the Grid, and put the elements in the desired grid cells by setting their `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties. Also do not set fixed Width and Height of the elements.

Comment: I tweak the xaml a little bit and that worked , i just changed the Height , Width parameters and now they are visible correctly .

Comment: If you want absolute positions and sizes use WinForms not WPF.

Comment: @Mary Not true. In WPF you can have absolute positions on a canvas without problems. In Winforms you can have size adjusting controls with i.e. TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: You also have LayoutTransform and RenderTransform at your disposal.

Comment: As @clemens stated, have a look at Grid.ColumnDefinitions and Row.RowDefinitions.  Once you get a grasp of that, this layout will become easy, and you wont have all of the magic numbers.  Here is a simple tutorial - https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: @Mary Using WinForms instead of WPF is nonsense. If you want absolute positioning, use a Canvas. However, OP doesn't want that anyway. What they apparently want is a Grid with fixed size left column and variable size right column.